# "State Service Application" cannot installed by Farm Configuration Wizard

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, error, service-application

I used **Farm Configuration wizard** which starts the **State Service Application**, the **State Service Application** started a few minutes, then it stopped automatically. And it has a error

> "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

Why **State Service Application** stopped automatically?

Comment: Have you tried creating the service application using `PowerShell`?

Comment: @AmalHashim, thank you. Not yet, I will try it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the existing service and create a new one using PowerShell

```
$serviceApp = New-SPStateServiceApplication -Name "State Service Application"
New-SPStateServiceDatabase -Name "SharePoint_Service_State" -ServiceApplication $serviceApp
New-SPStateServiceApplicationProxy -Name "State Service Application Proxy" -ServiceApplication $serviceApp -DefaultProxyGroup
```

Once this is done, you can go to Manage Service Applications and check the status

Also you can check it using

```
$MyStateService = Get-SPStateServiceApplication
$MyStateService.status
```